# Not updating button's data attribute

Tags: jquery

There are answers on here that show how to update a data attribute but in my case, it is not working. It's probably something simple. Here's my button:

```
<button type="submit" rel="popover" class="btn primary" id="save" 
        data-content="some content I want to change" data-placement="below" 
        data-original-title="some more content I want to change">Save
</button>
```

Here's my code to update the content data attribute:

`$('#save').data('content', 'something else');`

But nothing happens. I'm using a click event that is being fired successfully.

Comment: What does data('content') show?

Comment: What does "nothing happens" mean? Have you tried retrieving the data after? Please reproduce the problem on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Here we go (first time using jsfiddle) http://jsfiddle.net/T3kGe/

Comment: The data attributes are both used with the Bootstrap JS library: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: @alemaster it seems to be working for me, after I fixed your button selector to `#save` instead of `#save_btn`. http://jsfiddle.net/T3kGe/1/ What do you expect to happen when using data attributes?

Answer (score 0):

After testing on www.jsfiddle.net (thank you Xeon06), I've seen that all was working: [see it here](http://jsfiddle.net/vgeca/1/)

To see what has changed open the FireBug console (or developer tools console in Chrome)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6i2H.png)

Answer (score 0):

Testing on jsfiddle.net (thank you Xeon06) shows that everything is working correctly.

Take a look at the updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/T3kGe/5/

This should help explain how to store and retrieve values via jQuery's [$.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method.